# Best way to store chat messages in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, chat, store, messaging, instant

We are currently implementing an **Instant Messaging system** on our platform. We need to provide our users **a chat history** and be able to show the last 5 conversations that user had ( preview like on facebook).

ipso facto we necessarily need to think about how we can **store all these data**.

We are using **Elasticsearch** and we think that this could be a reliable solution to store chat messages and make them highly available for read operations.

Our question is, what would be **the best data structure within Elasticsearch** so that our read operations can be fast and not too heavy.

We thought of a lot of solution and this may be the best we came up with.

Our message representation could be :

```
{ 
   "ID" : 1,
   "sender" : "john",
   "receiver" : "doe",
   "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
   "date" : "timestamp"
}
```

We could use nested object to store messages within a conversation :

```
 {
     "ID" : 317,
     "participants" : "john, doe",
     "date" : "timestamp of the last received message",
     "messages": [
         {
            "ID": "49753",
            "sender" : "john", 
            "receiver" : "doe",
            "content" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
            "date" : "timestamp" 
         },
         {
            "ID": "49754",
            "sender" : "doe", 
            "receiver" :"john",
            "content" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
            "date" : "timestamp" 
         },....
               ]
}
```

We would like to have your feedback on this solution and also have your solutions if you have any better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Note:  This suggested solution is not only from the perspective of fast-reads (as requested by OP), but also with an eye toward minimizing indexing overhead.  Nested documents and their parents are written as a single block, so the addition of each additional "message" in the nested proposal would cause all previous message and conversation data in that conversation to be reindexed as well.*

**Here's my guess about Facebook's general approach to implementing Messages** (if you were to do something similar using Elasticsearch)

[image]

**Preview**:  (In `Messages` navbar dropdown, and on the left rail of the *Messages* page)

Shows a summary of the most recent conversations using:

- Composite headshots of the three most recent participants in the  - Ordered list of most recent three conversation participants.
- Number of additional participants if > 3
- Timestamp of most recent message in the conversation
- Snippet of the latest message in the conversation

**Message Pane**: (Center column of the *Messages* page)

- Shows all the messages in a conversation
- The Message Pane also repurposed for Message Search results, showing all messages containing the searched term.

**Search Box**:

- Typeahead:  (completes *on conversations* using matching participant names)
- Search: (searches *on messages* using matching text from message body)

---

The data structure driving the **preview**, would probably be in a `conversation` index (containing one document per conversation).  These documents would be updated each time a message is added to a conversation.  (Much like the parent record of your nested example doc).

This `conversation` data source is only used to draw the previews (fast filtering on conversation participants to ensure that you only see conversations you are a part of).

```
 {
     "ID" : 317,
     "participant_ids": [123456789, 987654321],
     "participant_names: ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"],
     "last_message_snippet" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...",
     "last_message_timestamp" : "timestamp of the last received message",
 }
```

There would be no nesting here b/c only the up-to-date conversation *summary* is needed, not the message.

Performance would be fast, because no scoring need take place, just a filter on [current user] in `participant_ids` and a descending sort by `last_message_timestamp`.

You could replicate the typeahead functionality using the Elasticsearch Term Suggester on the `participant_names` field.

The lower-number of `conversation` documents (vs `message` documents) would help  an index updated this frequently function well at scale.

To further scale this functionality, an [Index Per Timeframe](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html) indexing strategy could be used (with the timeframe being determined by say, the typical half-life of a conversation, as an example).

---

When *displaying* the **Messages** within a particular `conversation`, you'd be querying a `message` index carrying your message document example, but with a reference to the `conversation`

```
 {
     "ID" : 4828274,
     "conversation_id": 317,
     "conversation_participant_ids": [123456789, 987654321],
     "sender_id": 123456789,
     "sender_name: "John Doe",
     "message" : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
     "message_timestamp" : <timestamp>,
 }
```

Performance would be fast, because no scoring need take place, just a filter on  `conversation_id` and a descending sort by `message_timestamp`.

When *searching* **Messages** across conversations, you'd only need to index the `message` field.  (Following the Facebook implementation).

The the search query would be the search term filtered by [current user] in `conversation_participant_ids` with a descending sort by `message_timestamp`.

To minimize cross-talk in the search cluster when retrieving the messages for a conversation, you'd want to be sure to take advantage of [Elasticsearch's `routing` parameter (on indexing requests)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html) to explicitly co-locate all messages for a conversation on the same shard, using the `conversation_id` as the `routing` value when indexing new messages.

---

*Note:  Elasticsearch may turn out to be overkill* for implementing a solution that could largely be built off of another document store or relational database with text-search functionality.  By normalizing `conversation` and `message` in the above example, there is no longer any dependence on "nesting" in Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch *strengths* for this implementation include efficient caching of filtered search results, fast autocomplete, and fast text search, but a *weakness* of Elasticsearch is the need for enough memory to comfortably accommodate all of the indexed data.

The performance characteristics of a Messaging application dictate that *only the most recent messages* are likely to be accessed or searched with any frequency, so at some point, if your application needs to scale, you should plan out a way to archive older, not-recently-accessed messages in "cold-storage" such that they require fewer application resources, but can still be "thawed" quickly enough to serve a keyword search without excessive latency.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, I'll put that at use. The ensuing question is how to manage unread messages when the user is offline...

Comment: You're thinking about how to store chat messages and alert the recipient?  Not sure that you'd want to do much differently than with messages received while online (maybe a Boolean `viewed` flag?)

Comment: How do you suggest we would do that ? We were thinking about storing the unread messages like in a Redis list and when the user comes back online, POP unread messages from the list and finally index them. I don't really get how can get the same effect with a viewed flag, we would need a call back on when the user opens the conversation.

Comment: Why wouldn't you index them when sent?  Do you expect the majority of messages to remain unread for long periods of time?

Comment: We would but we have to know one way or another if the message was read to mark it as viewed or not. I will probably understand your point when we put that at test.

Comment: Why not stick with your Redis list idea for read/unread display state, but index unread messages immediately after they are sent to avoid unnecessary latency around message availability/searchability when the user comes back online.

Comment: This should do the trick, I will let you know, thanks again for the help.