# Profanity (bad words) filter for real-time chat, elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, chat, real-time, profanity

I need to create a room based chat app, that needs to support thousands of users at the same time.

The problem is, client wants to filter bad words from the messages.

Standard profanity filter libraries would not be a problem to use if the number of the users is low, but in this case performance of the filtering is the most important thing as the chat is real-time.

Libraries that uses NLP are mostly trained with english language datasets, and it will also not work for me since i need to filter bad words for couple of langugages.

The only remaining thing that comes to my mind is ElasticSearch.

Is there any solution that is good enough and can support large numbers of the users, something that would work like this :

bad_words = [badword1, badword2, badword3...]

Input message : "You are badword1, and i badword2 you!"

Output message: "You are ***, and i *** you"

If the solution can also handle cases where, for the example "badword1" is written as "bad_word1" or something like that, it would be a bonus.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Have a check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768944/elasticsearch-how-to-filter-hate-words-insults-in-search-analyze

Comment: @jaspreetchahal i came across this post, the closes solution would be the one on the c), but the problem is it uses regEx for detecting exact word, and as the author says, i don't know how it will scale with having a lot of words in total gathered from different languages.

Comment: How  is data sent to elastic search?. Best solution would be to not index such data at all

Comment: @jaspreetchahal what do you exactly mean by how data is sent ? I tried couple of solutions but nothing is decided yet, as i am inexperienced with elasticsearch and im still looking for right solution for this. I don't know even if elasticsearch could be used rightfully for something like chat app filtering or there are better approaches.

Comment: Elastic search is a data store. So before data is sent to elastic search , data can be curated. Regarding elastic search as primary data source for chat application , probably this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488727/best-way-to-store-chat-messages-in-elasticsearch